# Pandas can't find csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a dataframe using a csv file for an assignment however, every time I would run my program it would show me an error that the file couldn't be found. My code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('thefile')
```

The code returns an error no matter where I place my file. When I checked for the path using the code below:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

It showed me that the path is correct and it is looking inside the folder where my csv file is located but it still returns me the same error.

Comment: Try using the full path. Also could you include the error in the post

Comment: Don't argue with the interpreter. If it says it cannot find the file, then there is something you overlook.

Comment: Try pd.read_csv('thefile.csv') it may be looking for the file type.

Comment: What does `os.path.exists('thefile')` return?

Comment: Note that if you are using the Windows OS, it doesn't show file extension like `.csv` by default — you have to enable it to actually see the real filenames. See these [instructions](https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/show-hidden-files-folders-extensions.html).

Answer (score 3):

When reading in files, the 'thefile' must be followed by a .csv extension in the reference, as follows; 'thefile.csv'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  **.csv** behind the thefile,
without it, it doesn't know which file to look for it could be thefile.txt, thefile.conf, thefile.csv, thefile.....

So your code should look like this.

```
  import pandas as pd
  df = pd.read_csv('thefile.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved the issue.